# ggplot time series: messed up x axis for data with missing values

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, x-axis

I am creating time series plot for the following data:

```
#  Creating data set
year <-  c(rep(2018,4), rep(2019,4), rep(2020,4))
month_1 <-  c(2, 3, 7,  8, 6, 10, 11, 12,  5,  7,  8, 12)
avg_dlt_calc <- c(10, 20, 11, 21, 13,  7, 10, 15,  9, 14, 16, 32)
data_to_plot <- data.frame(cbind(year,month_1,avg_dlt_calc ))



ggplot(data_to_plot, aes(x = month_1)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = avg_dlt_calc), size = 0.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "months", limits = data_with_avg$month_1) +
  facet_grid(~year, scales = "free")
```

I am ok with the plot itself, but x-axis labels are messed up:

[image]

**How I can fix it?**

It is ok not to have labels for missing months (for example, for 2018 it will be only 2,3,7,8 - so it will be clear, that there is data only for those months).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A remedy is to coerce `month_1` to a `factor` and group the observations by year like so:

```
ggplot(data_to_plot, aes(x = as.factor(month_1), y = avg_dlt_calc, group = year)) +
  geom_line(size = 0.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "months") +
  facet_grid(~year, scales = "free")
```

Note that I've moved `y = avg_dlt_calc` inside `aes()` in `ggplot()` which is more idiomatic than your approach. You may use the `breaks` argument in `scale_x_discrete()` to set breaks manually, see `?scale_x_discrete`.

[image]

I think a fixed x-axis and adding points is more suitable for conveying the information that data is only available for some periods:

```
ggplot(data_to_plot, aes(x = as.factor(month_1), y = avg_dlt_calc, group = year)) +
  geom_line(size = 0.5) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "months") +
  facet_grid(~year, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: This is interesting solution, but what if I have 2 lines: `avg_dlt_standard <- c(rep(9,12)) 
data_to_plot <- data.frame(cbind(year,month_1,avg_dlt_calc,avg_dlt_standard ))`.  Second line will not have any missing values.  Before it was like this: `ggplot(data_to_plot, aes(x = month_1)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = avg_dlt_calc, colour = "DLT calculated"), size = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y = avg_dlt_standard, colour = "DLT standard"), size = 0.5) `